# is $y(t) = (x(t))^2$ non-linear and time-invariant system?

Tags: fourier-transform

i was able to show that it is not linear but for time-invariant I am not sure.
$y(t) = (x(t))^2$

Let $y(t)$ be the output corresponding to the input $x(t).$ Let $x_T(t) = (x(t-T))^2.$
Then the output $y_T(t)$ corresponding to the input $x_T(t)$ is

$y_T(t) = (x_T(t-T))^2 = (x(t-T))^2 = y(t-T)$ -> time-invariant

Thanks for the help!

Comment: you've confused yourself, by calling $(x(t_T))^2$ "$x_T$", when it should really be called $y_T$. if you want to call anything $x_T$, it should probably be $x_T(t) = x(t-T)$. The second approach makes no sense, you're calculating $y(y(x_T(t))$.

Comment: What is $x_T(t-T)$ since you have defined $x_T$ (with no arguments, just a symbol) as $(x(t-T))^2$ which _is_ a function of $t$? In the next sentence, you write $x_T(t)$ which you haven't defined anywhere. -1 pending appropriate **edits**.  DO NOT answer in the _comments_; **edit** your question to correct the mistakes.  You can edit the question by clicking on the link `Edit` below your question.

Comment: You **still** have it wrong.  The output at any time is then_square_ of the input at that specific time.  If the input is $x_T(t) = (x(t-T))^2$, then the output is the _square_ of this quantity, that is, $$y_T(t) = \big[x_T(t)\big]^2 = \big[(x(t-T))^2\big]^2= (x(t-T))^4$$ etc.

Answer (score 4):

The system defined through the transfer function expression:
$$
y(t)=(x(t))^2
$$
is *Time Invariant*, since the time is explicitely not included in the expression, besides $x(t)$, and $y(t)$.

Also, as you can see, the expression $H(x,t)=x^2$ is non linear in $x$, so the system is thus *Non Linear*.

**How to Check if a System is Time Invariant?**

In general, for a system defined as:
$$
y(t)=H(x(t),t)
$$

You can assess Time Invariance by comparing the output with the input delayed $H(x(t-\tau),t) $ with respect to the delayed output $y(t-\tau)$:
$$
H \text{ Time Invariant}: \\
y(t-\tau)=H(x(t-\tau),t-\tau)=H(x(t-\tau),t)
$$

This is evident. The condition requests that the $t$ variable present in $H(x,t)$ does not exist.

In our case, this is again evident, since $H(x,t)=x^2$ and there is no time variable $t$.

Compare with this Time Variant system: $y(t)=x(t)^t$. Now you can realize the difference.

**How to Check if a System is Linear?**

Finally, you can assess a Linear System by checking the Transfer Function is Linear in $x$:
$$
H \text{ Linear}: \\
H(ax_1(t),t)=aH(x_1(t),t) \ \forall a\\
H(x_1(t)+x_2(t),t)=H(x_1(t),t)+H(x_2(t),t)\\
$$

Note, Linearity is not applied in the $t$ variable. Only in the inputs through outputs.

As you can see, the system is Non Linear, since
$(ax(t))^2 \ne ax(t)^2$ and $(x_1(t)+x_2(t))^2 \ne x_1(t)^2+x_2(t)^2$ which fail both asserts.

**What happens when I don't have the expression H in real life?**

As you can see, all these conditions are easy to test for numerical expressions, but in real life, you have to test them case by case. *Almost always*, they will fail, hence, the Time Variant, Non Linear will be at some degree the often system case to deal with.

**Simple Examples of Time Invariance and Linearity**

As above, here are few very simple examples of systems, defined through diferent expressions for $H(x,t)$. You can see now your system is Non Linear Invariant, since the transfer function expression is non linear in $x$:

- $H(x,t)=ax$: Linear Time Invariant System
- $H(x,t)=ax^2$: Non-Linear Time Invariant System
- $H(x,t)=tx$: Linear Time Variant System
- $H(x,t)=tx^2$: Non-Linear Time Variant System

Comment: I'll upvote if you add an additional good answer as to why it is non-linear

Comment: @DanBoschen A pleasure!, but don't ask me to say the system is Static...

Comment: I just realized the OP asked about Linearity and Time Invariance. A better answer is now in place.